# Customize Admin Users Screen based on Role

Tags: admin, users, user-roles

I've added a role of "Customer" and I am working on customizing the Users Screen for that role. What I'd like to do is customize columns based on that particular role.

**Note:**

For example, take a look at the screenshot. How would I remove the reference to the posts column for *only* the customer role?

[image: Example of current "Customer" screen]

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the column, but remove the number listed there for 'Customer' users? It wouldn't make sense to remove the column entirely, right? I say that because you could easily be viewing a list of users, where some are 'Customers' and others are some other role, and would thus need that column.

Comment: @tnorthcutt - Note that I am looking at the "Customer" filter (see the *Customer* in bold in the screenshot). I was able to get it working (see my answer below), I'm just wanting to make sure I've got as good a practice as I can get.

Comment: Gotcha - I noticed the filter, but didn't realize you'd only want it on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mike23 for the tip. Here's the code that I'm using to add a column to *only* the "customer" role:

```
if( $_GET['role'] == "customer" ) { 

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_ecommerce_column');
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'manage_ecommerce_column', 10, 3);


function add_ecommerce_column($columns) {
        $columns['ecommerce'] = 'Ecommerce';
    return $columns;

}

function manage_ecommerce_column($empty='', $column_name, $id) {
    if( $column_name == 'ecommerce' ) {
        return $column_name.$id;    
        }
}
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions for improvement are very welcomed.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're customizing this interface, for you the administrator? Because if you're doing that with the customer in mind (what does the customer see when he visits this page) then it's better to `use current_user_can`

Comment: Mike, the customer won't see this page. It is only for administrators or other roles that have the appropriate access.

Answer (score 1):

#### Manage Columns

It's pretty straight forward using the `manage_{post-type-name}_columns` filter: Just switch per [`$capability`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) and unset what you don't need in the `$post_columns` array.

```
function wpse19435_manage_columns( $posts_columns )
{
    // First role: add a column - take a look at the second function
    if ( current_user_can( $capability_admin ) )
    {
        $posts_columns['some_column_name'] = _x( 'Whatever', 'column name' );
    }
    // second role: remove a column
    elseif ( current_user_can( $capability_other_role ) )
    {
        unset( $posts_columns['comments'] );
    }
    // default
    else
    {
        // do stuff for all other roles
    }

    return $posts_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_{post-type-name}_columns', 'wpse19435_manage_columns' );
```

**Add a column**

```
function wpse19435_manage_single_column( $column_name, $id ) 
{
    switch( $column_name ) 
    {
        case 'some_column_name' :
            // do stuff
            break;

        default :
            // do stuff
            break;
    }

}
add_action('manage_{post-type-name}_custom_column', 'wpse19435_manage_single_column', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Kaiser, thanks for this. I'll experiment with it and update the question accordingly.

Comment: Kaiser, I took a closer look at the code and it is possible that you may have misunderstood the question? I'm actually wanting to add/remove columns to the Users Screen, rather than adding and removing columns to a post type screen. Take a look at the screenshot and updated example copy.

Comment: @Jonathan Wold No, haven't missunderstood it, but Q/A over here are for a broader community than just the questioner (it's not a usual forum). So: It's a more general answer, but you won#t have to exchange anything than the hook name. Sry for not mentioning it, thought you got around it with 176 rep points...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can). With that you can filter your code by roles, and then do whatever you want to customize the interface.

Quick and dirty, with CSS. Put this in your functions.php :

```
function add_custom_admin_styles() {
    /* Customers */
    if(current_user_can('customer')){
        echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            .column-posts{display:none!important;}  
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_custom_admin_styles');
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the thought. The difference here, at least as I see it, is that I'm trying to customize the view of a _selection_ of users (in this case, "customer"), irrespective of the role of the user _viewing_ the selection.

Comment: Ok, I see, in that case perhaps you can try something like `if( $_GET['role'] == "customer" ) etc.` as the `role` variable is present in the URL when you visit the users.php page in the admin.

Comment: Mike, that's an interesting, thought - thank you! I may give that a try..

Comment: display:none is almost never the right way to do something like this, fwiw. I'd bet (but don't know for sure) that there's a better way.

Comment: @tnorthcutt, true that's why I said "quick and dirty". If he (the admin), is the only one having access to this screen it should be enough though.