# Remove the Edit button in posts for permalinks on certain user roles? WP 3.3

Tags: posts, permalinks, admin, user-roles

I am using Wordpress 3.3.2 with the following plugin:
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

The plugin works perfectly but the author said there is currently no way to achieve this from the plugin, So I am wondering if there is either another plugin or any code modifications I can make to achieve them.

1. I created a custom user role Called "Member"
2. I applied certain permissions so the user can only sees options to make posts in the backend.
3. When making a post, the user does not see the "Edit" option to change the permalink.
4. The problem comes after the user submits the Post. Right below the post title field it shows the permalink and shows an "Edit" button which allows the user to change the permalink.

Is there any way to remove either the "Edit" button so they can't edit the permalink, or removing that entire line altogether so the permalink doesn't show for them at all?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like (in your functions.php file);

```
if(current_user_can('member')){  

add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'perm', '',4);

function perm($return, $id, $new_title, $new_slug){
    
    $post = get_post( $id );

    if( ! $post || ( $post->post_type !== 'testimonials' ) )
    {
        return $return;
    }

    return preg_replace(
        '/<span id="edit-slug-buttons">.*<\/span>|<span id=\'view-post-btn\'>.*<\/span>/i', 
        '', 
        $return
    );
}
```

To give credit where credit is due, everything between

<strike>`if( $_GET['role'] == "member" ) {`</strike>

and

<strike>`}`</strike>

...is directly taken from this Question & Answer [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/customize-admin-users-screen-based-on-role) courtesy of **Jonathan Wold**

## UPDATE

The conditional if statement of;

`if( $_GET['role'] == "member" ) {//code here }`

was replaced with,

**`if(current_user_can('member')){ //code here}`**

...in this instance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and link! Would I edit the functions.php file from my theme, or from the wp-includes folder? I want to make sure if I upgrade WP, the change isn't lost... but if there is no way around that then no biggie :)

Comment: I tried putting that in both locations, with no success in either.

Comment: You should **never** edit the WP core files. Only edit files contained within your Themes/your-theme folder. Change `testimonial` to match your post type. If its just the regular **post** then type `post`. This code should go into your functions.php file within your theme folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification on where to place the code. I've tried adding the code to both functions.php files(not at the same time of course).. I even changed the user to administrator and tried other post types. Tried capitalizing first letter of the member role as well. Tried putting it at the top and at the bottom of the functions.php page. I've spent about 4-5 hours googling hooks and functions and forums, but I still can not seem to get this to work.

Comment: Nm, the code works... just not with the IF statement. I am going to see what I can find.

Comment: What about this instead; `if(current_user_can('member')){
 // do your code here
}`

Comment: Flawless!! Works perfect!! Thank you soo much :). Would you happen to be able to explain why one worked and the other wouldn't? If not, it's cool.. I will research it :).

Comment: Its likely because the $_GET is actually looking for an instance of `role` = `member` in the URL of which it doesn't exist in this instance. It occurred to me that it wouldn't work for your purpose. Using `current_user_can` is actually the proper way to go about it and that's a function directly from the WordPress API. Its meant to be used in this instance. Of course that's not to say that there aren't other ways to achieve the same result because there's often many ways to arrive at _x_ but we should always be using in built WP functions wherever possible.

Comment: Definitely appreciate your help :). One last question, how did you know to use "get_sample_permalink_html" ? When I was troubleshooting, I googled everywhere and even in the codex to see what that function did and what the arguments( 'perm', '',4) you put in afterwords did but with no success

Comment: WP has more functions you can poke a stick at. Not all of these are documented in the Codex sadly. Although there are source-documented API search engines around, I often resort to searching the core files myself (locally) using Notepad++'s "find in all" search function or a program called AstroGrep. Usually I open the file in which controls the "problem" in question and reverse engineer the process - you'll notice that `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` controls the build of the post edit screen & on line 295 references our function. From there you can do a find all & learn about the function.

Comment: ...also `perm` is just the name of the function. So it goes `hook_name, function_name`. Notice that the function is named **perm** ; you can in-fact call it whatever you want, just make sure the add_action calls the correct function name. The numbers that proceed are related to execution/priorities (take a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action))

Comment: Still seems working in 2022. I wanted to hide the whole "line" so i just `return "";` 
Thank you gentlemen.

Comment: @ViktorBorítás you're welcome, thanks for confirming it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an additional to accomplish this, the following code worked for me as well but it didn't make use of the IF statement for the user role. This would be added to the functions.php file. I found the information at:
https://gist.github.com/1967124

```
 <?php

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_edit_permalinks_admin_css');

function hide_edit_permalinks_admin_css()
{
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#titlediv
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#edit-slug-box
{
display: none;
}
-->
</style>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Also here is another similar post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/removing-edit-permalink-view-custom-post-type-areas

Comment: I had to use `#edit-slug-buttons` instead of `#edit-slug-box`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the role object
$role = get_role( 'editor' );

// remove cap
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_post' );
```

Not sure but this should work, isn't it?